# Swift: Sorting Objects by Function Value

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, object

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by the return value of one of their functions/methods. My class is as below:

```
class Shift{
var Name: String

var Deliveries: [Delivery] = []
var SalesPercentage: Double = 0.0
var LabelForecast: Double = 0.0
var PromotionModsChanging: Double = 0.0

var ShortName: String{
    get{
        return Name[0...2]
    }
}

init(Name: String){
    self.Name = Name
}

func getSales() -> Double{
    return (SalesPercentage / 100) * Settings.ExpectedWeeklySales
}

func totalWeight() -> Double{
    var total: Double = 0.0

    // Add total Deliveries Weight
    for delivery: Delivery in Deliveries{
        total = total + delivery.DeliveryWeight()
    }

    // Add Sales Weight
    total = total + (getSales() * 0.2)

    // Add labels Weight measured at 100 labels per hour
    total = total + (LabelForecast * 0.6)

    // Add Promotion Mods Changing measured at 45 Minutes per mod. Ladder racks and grocery shelving should be classed as 0.5 mods each.
    total = total + (PromotionModsChanging * 45)

    return total
}


}
```

The array that they are stored in is as:

```
var Shifts: [Shift] = []
```

Which I've then appended Shift objects to. Then I am trying to find a way to organise the Shifts array by the returned value from the totalWeight() function. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would sort the array of `Shift`s into ascending order:

```
let sorted = shifts.sorted { $0.totalWeight() < $1.totalWeight() }
```

Alternatively, instead of creating a new array and assigning the sorted `shifts` to that; you could sort `shifts` like so:

```
shifts.sort { $0.totalWeight() < $1.totalWeight() }
```

Bear in mind, the immediately above code will only work because you've declared `shifts` as variable.

Comment: Can't believe it. Tried it already but had a syntax error so wouldn't work. Cheers bro